# Vue-router in-Component guards won't trigger router.push() is called

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In-Component guard `beforeRouteLeave` is triggered when clicking on a `<router-link to="/">`. However, it's not triggered when I call `router.push({ path: "/" })` programmatically.

Is there something wrong with that?

**Edit**

I just tried to make a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-bush-c3b4x?file=/pages/item.vue) and found out it occurs just if navigating to the same path with dynamic parameter.

For example navigating from `/item/1` to `/item/2` causes this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is an unexpected behavior, it'd help more if you provide more context.

**EDIT**

You don't actually **leave the route** if you just pass a different parameter, which is why `beforeRouteLeave` doesn't get triggered.

Instead, you might want to use `beforeRouteUpdate`

For more information about **In-Component Guards** see the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

Comment: You mean it should be triggered?

Comment: Yes, it works just fine for me when navigating away in all cases.

Comment: I found out it happens in another situation. Question is now edited.

Comment: It's triggered. But is it OK for avoiding navigation if any unsaved data exists? It's seems it's not working this way.

Comment: Yes, you can still achieve this by `beforeRouteUpdate`, but it triggers when anything in your route `fullPath` changes, so if you have multiple variables in your route (e.g more than 1 param or query) then it might be a good idea to compare the `to` and `from` objects before running your logic to make sure that this is the case you want.

Comment: I can't get `beforeRouteUpdate` to trigger when just changing params. The params are "hidden" (i.e. not part of the path), can this be the reason it's not triggering for me?